# avoid $( expansion in Qliksense

Tags: qliksense

I have rest api which decrypts the token passed to it and returns the actual value.
The token can sometime contains $( values and hence this is causing issues in the post call to the api

```
[dbtable]:
SELECT X
FROM "table" WHERE key='1234';

Let v_C= Peek('X',0,'dbtable');

//create the json request

Let vRequestBody='[';
Let vRequestBody = vRequestBody&'{"troup":"CB","tt":"CBA","tk":"$(v_C)"}';
Let vRequestBody = vRequestBody&']';

LIB CONNECT TO 'postapi';

RestConnectorMasterTable:
SQL SELECT 
    "data"
FROM JSON (wrap on) "root"
WITH CONNECTION (BODY "$(vRequestBody)" );
```

its working for rest of the values. But for values with "$(" the value of v_C turns NULL due to $ expansion. is there a way where I can avoid $ expansion and pass the value as it is to the body of the api call in qlik sense

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is quite common with APIs where they can have ways they want things passing that "confuse" Qlik Sense's parser. Generally the way around it is to put in a placeholder and then replace that with the real value later or use a `chr()` command to get the character you want. I think the latter should work in this situation:

```
Let vRequestBody = vRequestBody&'{"troup":"CB","tt":"CBA","tk":"' & chr(36) & '(v_C)"}';
```

Hope that works.

Comment: Nope. This did not work. `WITH CONNECTION (BODY "$(vRequestBody)" );` causes $expansion as chr(36) is $ only

Comment: Ah yes, there's more to it than that, sorry. There will be a way of "escaping" the dollar I think, I'm just not sure what it is. I know that using `""` gives you `"` inverted commas, could be worth trying `$$` or `\$`... I don't think URL encoding it will work as it will try to re-encode it I think, but you could try with `&#36;`. Hard to say what will work without having the API to test it against.